# Is there a reason no links show up when using mech-dump?

Tags: perl, mechanize

I'm trying to practice pulling salary information from openpayroll.com. I need to be able to analyze the links on a given page and click on them if need be. When I run the following

```
mech-dump --all https://openpayrolls.com/other/utah-carbon-county-housing-authority
```

It only returns information regarding the headers but the links part is empty, i.e. it returns `--> Links:`  and that's it. The page, however, is full of links. Do I need to pass an additional option to access all the links on the webpage?

Comment: When I run the command you provided, it returns: 403 forbidden. If I visit https://openpayrolls.com/other/utah-carbon-county-housing-authority in the browser I get a cloudflare captcha "verify that you are a human" checkbox. That might be the problem?

Comment: Is there a general way around captcha and other authentication steps that redirect requests? Also, I've now been blocked from the site. Is it typical for sites to block IPs due to mech-dump requests?

Comment: @DavidG. They're most likely blocking you because of the `User-Agent` header, this could be a Cloudflare rule. A way to get around this is to spoof your `User-Agent` header, however if they have a Captcha it may be more difficult once you're passed the block.